# Обстоятельство или сравнение?

Tags: пунктуация

Тишина мне верна как мать — требуется ли запятая?

В тексте: тишина мне верна как мать, а вот всякое слово ненадёжно.

Comment: Требуется иное словосочетание. Что или кто угодно, но не мать же!

Comment: И еще требуется контекст, без него такие вопросы не решаются.

Comment: Почему нет? Я вообразил себе заботу, тепло, исходящее от тишины, таящиеся в ней творческие возможности, близость к душе человека: всё надежно, пока им не высказано слово. Это противопоставление всех людей (шум, исходящий от всех высказываний) и матери (глубокая духовная тишина, не знающая шума). Что Вам не нравится?

Comment: Тогда это хорошая мысль, почти как у Манлельштама. Да обретут мои уста Первоначальную немоту,Как кристаллическую ноту, Что от рождения чиста! То же настроение...

Comment: Так, чем больше слов и строчек, тем меньше им веры... Хорошая нам всем наука. А как же Хармс со своей молитвой: «Награди меня, Господи, словом Твоим, чтобы гремело оно, восхваляя чертоги Твои»? А «мать» всё-таки убрал, или заменил бы, к примеру, на «материнский капитал».

Answer (score 1):

1. А мне кажется, что нельзя ***и так и сяк***.  Ведь текст уже задан, структура определена, а значит, степень нашей свободы ограничена.

***Тишина мне верна как мАть, а вот всякое слово ненадЁжно.***

Это сложносочиненное предложения со значением сопоставления. Расстановка логических ударений вполне ясная: предложения делится на две фразы, обособить оборот нет возможности.

2. Но попробуем **изменить структуру**:

***Тишина мне всегдА верна, как (и) мать, а вот всякое слово ненадЁжно***.

При такой расстановке ударений оборот нужно обособить.

3. Итак, решаем задачу  с помощью интонационного анализа, то есть не обособляем оборот.  А как же правила? С ними тоже все в порядке.

После проведения интонационного анализа становится окончательно ясно: здесь возможно только **обстоятельственное значение оборота**  (обособления нет),  так как именно оно соответствует грамматической форме предложения. Что касается  варианта с уподоблением, то он по форме не проходит.

Итак, делаем выводы:

1. Вариант «и так и сяк» при уже заданной структуре предложения  встречается исключительно редко.
2. Принятое нами **интонационное решение** полностью соответствует  правилу Розенталя!

Answer (score 0):

Имхо, можно и так, и сяк. Можно оборот с *как* рассматривать в качестве уподобления: *Тишина мне верна, подобно матери.*

> 3. Сравнительный оборот с союзом ***как*** выделяется запятыми в следующих случаях:
>
> - 1. если он обозначает **уподобление** (***как*** имеет значение
>      ‘подобно’): *Воздух чист и свеж, **как поцелуй ребёнка*** (Лермонтов);
>      *Под ним, **как океан,** синеет степь кругом* (Крылов.); *Вот с неба звёзды глянут, и, **как река,** засветит Млечный Путь* (Фет)...
>
> http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147,3

Можно и в качестве обстоятельства образа действия: *Тишина мне верна по-матерински.*

> 4. Сравнительный оборот с союзом ***как*** не выделяется запятыми:
>
> - 1. если на первый план выступает значение **обстоятельства образа
>      действия** (обороты с ***как*** можно заменить в этих случаях формой
>      творительного падежа существительного или наречием): *Я посмотрел на неё **как дурак*** (Тургенев)...
>
> (Там же.)

Выбор за автором! А если автор захочет, мы сами можем ему провести интонационный анализ и подобрать подходящее правило :)